# AnyLogic Batching agents i.t.o Weight

Tags: anylogic

How do I set the batch size i.t.o the weight I want to batch? I am currently simulating a potato plant.  And the potatoes(agent) all have their own weight due to the randomness of potatoes, but now I must batch them into 10Kg bags. The weight should just be over 10kg but not smaller, so it is going to be 9.9kg plus one more potato.

The F1 help function suggests to use a customized Queue. But I do not know how to go forward with that option.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a "Wait" object with infinite capacity. Whenever a potatoe is added, check the total weight and if they are above your threshold, you can use `wait.freeAll()`. This will send them into a downstream batch object.

Make sure to change the batch size to the number of potatoes in the "wait" object before you the the freeAll() method,so that all freed potatoes are batched together. You can do that dynamically using `batch.set_batchSize(x)`

cheers

Comment: btw: Are you sure your potatoes need to be agents? Seems overkill, to be honest. Maybe a simple Java object with the core characteristics (weight, type) would suffice? If you are gong to have millions of them in your model, agents might turn into a memory problem because each agent carries a lot of invisible baggage that your potatoes don't need...

Comment: Thanks for the help on the wait block, it is working just as I want it to.  But just another question if you do not mind?  You suggested to rather create an object with weight and size characteristics, I only have the PLE(Personal Learning Edition) that can only create 50 000 dynamic agents.  When I rather use an object will I be able to simulate more potatoes in my simulation?

Comment: no :-) But you can always design your model in a clever way to reduce total object/agent count, like with batching or turning a few potatoes into one agent when you don't need their individual characteristics...

Comment: Thank you, you really helped me allot!